# unti testing in sails js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, sails.js, waterline

I'm starting a new sails project, and the first thing I did, I generated a model and controller for "User". all rest functionality works alright. now I want to get into test driven development, following on [this official link](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/testing), I made folders as stated in the page, but I can't get it to work.

```
> cd myapp/test/unit
mocha "*/**/*.js"
```

it says

> 1) UsersModel #find() should check find function:
>        ReferenceError: User is not defined

in `./test/unit/models/Users.test.js` I added

```
var User = require('../../../api/models/User');
```

but I have a new error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

I logged `User` into console and saw it was the plain object that I defined in models folder, not the waterline model associated with it!

how can I get this official test to work? what am I missing?